# Jquery scroll to div, custom position?

Tags: jquery, scroll

So I am using this script to scroll to a div in JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
});
});
```

The problem is when it scrolls to a div, the title (say the first 20px) is hidden because of a header top bar div implemented on my page. how would I control the scroll so it stops early so that you can view the whole div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the size of the header so that it stops at that location.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top+20}, 800);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same line you already have:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
```

You just need to play with the `scrollTop` value. For example

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 50}, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#your_custom_position_id').position().top}, SPEED);
```